# less or equal constraint is always equal

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm new to iOS programming specially working with Storyboards. I was trying to achieve a `UILabel` which should has a max width but it should change based on the text inside so I gave it these constraints

[image]

and in code after setting text I'm calling `sizeToFit()` but the result isn't what I wanted

[image]

as you can see it's always equal. how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't you want >= constraints?  Ie, the text field will be at least 16 away from the edge, but possibly more.

Comment: two errors there - 1. you dont specify the location (nor width really) just by two >= and <= constraints, 2. it seems that one of your constraints does not really specify what you want. See my answer for the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that your constraints are ambiguous. You are saying that the `label` leading anchor has to be greater than or equal to `superview`'s leading anchor + 16, and `label` trailing anchor has to be less than or equal to `superview`'s trailing anchor - 16. But that means that the label can be **anywhere** between those two limits.

You have to add at least one more constraint that would tell the autolayout **where** to place that label (where exactly between those two limits). E.g., add a constraint saying that the `label`'s centerX anchor should be equal to `superview`'s centerX anchor. That would place the `label` in the center of the `view`, and those >= and <= constraints would keep that label from expanding beyond those limits.

**EDIT**

Also, it seems from how the storyboards show this, that your trailing space constraint is not correct, and you should change it from `<=` to `>=`. Make sure that in the inspector it says this (the view that you screenshot is pretty confusing):

[image]

> `superview.trailing >= label.trailing + 16`

and

> `label.leading >= superview.leading + 16`

Comment: thanks but there were no error given by Xcode. I just mistakenly used less or equal instead of greater or equal

Comment: @Amir_P what do you mean no error? it does not crash.. but your constraints there are not good

Comment: @Amir_P read through the answer, and follow my instructions, and you will get what you want

Answer (score 2):

You want the leading and trailing space to be *16 or more*, which means you want a >= constraint. That way the leading and trailing space can increase to allow for the intrinsic width of the text field as determined by its content.

The way you have it now, the leading and trailing space must be *16 or less* which means that a very wide text field content could cause the text field to be less than 16 from the leading and trailing edges but it can't be more than 16 so you are going to hit the "equals" part in most cases.